# In Mongo, how do I determine how deeply nested an object is?

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB to store an object which contains a sub-object which [normally] just contains name/value pairs of strings.  We are seeing some data corruption where the objects are becoming more deeply nested than they should.

For example, this is a valid object:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "d": { "a":"foo", "b":"bar" } }
```

We are seeing some invalid objects, like the following:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "d": { "a":"foo", "b":{ "c":"bar" } } }
```

or:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "d": { "a":{ "z":"foo" }, "b":"bar" } }
```

I would like to write a query to find all corrupted values.  Anything where a value in the 'd' property is an object instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.foo.find(function() { for (f in this) { var v = this[f]; if (typeof v == "object" && !(v instanceof Array) && !(v instanceof ObjectId) && !(v instanceof NumberLong) && !(v instanceof Date) && !(v instanceof BinData)) return true; } return false; })
```

Type checking is ugly, can it be done better?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need just check type of 'b' property:

```
// matches if 'b' is a string - valid objects
db.things.find( { "d.b" : { $type : 2 } } ); 

 // matches if 'b' is a object - invalid objects
db.things.find( { "d.b" : { $type : 3 } } );
```

[Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24type)

Comment: The only problem is the exact value being corrupted is different each time.  For some objects it is the 'b' property, but for others it's a different property.

Comment: @AgileJon: the only solution here will be to run such a query for each possibly "corrupt" property or use the `$or` operator. There's really no "object property wildcard" syntax available.